# Deleting duplicates based on multiple columns but selecting which last one to keep, using R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a script that would delete based on duplicate values in three columns. There are way more than three columns but i want to delete based on those specific ones

```
DF2021 <-DF2021 [!duplicated (DF2021[,c("column1","column2","column3")]),]
```

The script above works and it leaves me with one row for each time there is a duplicate based on those three columns.

The next step is where I wonder how to make sure I'am left with the row based on criteria. For example I want the row with the least NA's.

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column 7
    Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm  Hospital    NA
    Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm     NA       NA
    Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    NA       NA       NA
    Feb     Thu    2020   Red     NA       NA       NA
    Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm     NA       NA
    Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm   Garden    Run
    Mar     Thu    2020   Red     Cold   Desk      Bus
```

In the end I would expect the duplicate value to leave me with three rows

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column 7
   Jan      Tue   2020    Blue    Warm   Hospital   NA
   Feb      Thu   2020     Red    Warm   Garden    Run
   Mar      Thu   2020     Red    Cold   Desk      Bus
```

Note I am left with the rows that have the most completed row or based with the least NA.

UPDATE: I meant to show the most completed row or the row with the most filled columns. Initially the question made it seem like I was looking for only columns with completed columns. I should that one of the rows does not have column 7 completed but I still want the data to pull that dataset regardless if the columns are completed it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `base R` approach after doing your first task to remove the duplicated values:

```
#Code
DF2021 <- DF2021[complete.cases(DF2021),]
```

The output will be:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5  column6
1     Jan     Tue    2020    Blue    Warm Hospital
6     Feb     Thu    2020     Red    Warm   Garden
7     Mar     Thu    2020     Red    Cold     Desk
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
DF2021 <- structure(list(column1 = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Feb", "Mar"), column2 = c("Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Thu", "Thu", 
"Thu", "Thu"), column3 = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L), column4 = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", 
"Red", "Red"), column5 = c("Warm", "Warm", NA, NA, "Warm", "Warm", 
"Cold"), column6 = c("Hospital", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Garden", "Desk"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I should have gone from 488 rows to 409 meaning 79 would be pulled. However when i ran the script above it just pulled 8 rows. Trying to figure out why. Still looking at the dataset to see what happened.

Comment: Ok so i see that the complete.cases function only pulls the rows that are completely filled in. I should have been more specific and i apologize. What i meant to do is basically grab the row with the most completed columns rather than completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

We could group by the first 3 columns, then `slice` the rows with the least number of NA on the rest of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
        group_by(column1, column2, column3) %>%
        slice(which.min(rowSums(is.na(select(cur_data(), column4:column7))))) %>%
        ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6  column7
#  <chr>   <chr>     <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
#1 Feb     Thu        2020 Red     Warm    Garden   Run    
#2 Jan     Tue        2020 Blue    Warm    Hospital <NA>   
#3 Mar     Thu        2020 Red     Cold    Desk     Bus
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Feb", "Mar"), column2 = c("Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Thu", "Thu", 
"Thu", "Thu"), column3 = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L), column4 = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", 
"Red", "Red"), column5 = c("Warm", "Warm", NA, NA, "Warm", "Warm", 
"Cold"), column6 = c("Hospital", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Garden", "Desk"
), column7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Run", "Bus")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: No cause that would delete the whole row if there is at least one na. I need something that is not all or nothing, but relative.